# Build XML from table

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, stringbuilder

I have a table that has repeated `OrderId`s, but also having detail information in the row.  I am using a `StringBuilder` to create the XML.

How do I string build using a `for-each` loop to build XML. I don't want to repeat the header information, only loop through detail for how ever many rows are there for that distinct `OrderId`.

Example data in table

```
OrderId - CustomerId - ItemId - Price
123       JONES        838483   3.99
123       JONES        859300   4.99
874       ROCKY        838483   1.99
874       ROCKY        838543   2.99
```

Desired Output:

```
foreach (var o in sdr)
```

applied to the following XML:

```
<orders>
    <order>
        <orderid>123</orderid>
        <Customerid>JONES</CustomerId>
        <items>
            <itemid>838483</itemid>
            <price>3.99</price>
            <itemid>859300</itemid>
            <price>4.99</price>
        </items>
    </order>
    <order>
        <orderid>874</orderid>
        <Customerid>ROCKY</CustomerId>
        <items>
            <itemid>838483   </itemid>
            <price>1.99</price>
            <itemid>838543</itemid>
            <price>2.99</price>
        </items>
    </order>
</orders>
```

HERE IS MY ATTEMPT

foreach (var o in sdrForEach)
                 {

```
                 string currentOrderId = sdrForEach.GetValue(0).ToString();


                 countcycle = countcycle + 1;

                 if (countcycle == 1)
                 {
                         string orderId = sdrForEach.GetValue(0).ToString();
                         string account = sdrForEach.GetValue(1).ToString();
                         string customerId = sdrForEach.GetValue(2).ToString();
                         string orderType = sdrForEach.GetValue(3).ToString();
                         string fullname = sdrForEach.GetValue(4).ToString();
                         string address1 = sdrForEach.GetValue(5).ToString();
                         string address2 = sdrForEach.GetValue(6).ToString();
                         string city = sdrForEach.GetValue(7).ToString();
                         string state = sdrForEach.GetValue(8).ToString();

                         string phone1 = sdrForEach.GetValue(23).ToString();
                         string phone2 = sdrForEach.GetValue(24).ToString();
                         string phone3 = sdrForEach.GetValue(25).ToString();
                         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone1)) { phone1 = ""; }
                         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone2)) { phone2 = ""; }
                         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone3)) { phone3 = ""; }

                         string notes = sdrForEach.GetValue(28).ToString();
                         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(notes)) { notes = ""; }


                     myStringXml.Append("<service_orders> ");
                     myStringXml.Append("<service_order> ");
                     myStringXml.Append("<number>" + orderId + "</number> ");
                     myStringXml.Append("<account>" + account +"</account>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<service_type>" + orderType + "</service_type>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<description></description>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<customer>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<customer_id>" + customerId + "</customer_id>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<first_name>" + fullname + "</first_name>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<last_name>" + fullname + "</last_name>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<email>" + orderType + "</email>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<phone1>" + phone1 + "</phone1>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<phone2>" + phone2 + "</phone2>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<phone3>" + phone3 + "</phone3>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<address1>" + address1 + "</address1>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<address2>" + address2 + "</address2>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<city>" + city + "</city>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<state>" + state + "</state>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<zip>" + orderType + "</zip>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<latitude></latitude>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<longitude></longitude>");
                     myStringXml.Append("</customer>");
                     myStringXml.Append("<notes count=" + Constants.dispatchObjects.DOUBLE_QUOTE + Constants.dispatchObjects.NOTECOUNT + Constants.dispatchObjects.DOUBLE_QUOTE + ">");
                     myStringXml.Append("<note created_at='' author=''>" + notes + "</note>");
                     myStringXml.Append(" </notes>");

                 }



                       string itemPrice = sdrForEach.GetValue(12).ToString();
                       string itemId = sdrForEach.GetValue(13).ToString();
                       string itemDescription = sdrForEach.GetValue(16).ToString();
                       string itemSequence = sdrForEach.GetValue(29).ToString();
                       string qty = sdrForEach.GetValue(14).ToString();
                       string volume = sdrForEach.GetValue(19).ToString();
                       string inventoryType = sdrForEach.GetValue(21).ToString();
                       string storeStop = sdrForEach.GetValue(17).ToString();
                       string setupTime = sdrForEach.GetValue(18).ToString();
                       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(setupTime)){setupTime = "";}





                 myStringXml.Append("<items>");
                 myStringXml.Append("<item>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<sale_sequence>"+ itemSequence +"</sale_sequence>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<item_id>"+ itemId +"</item_id>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<serial_number></serial_number>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<description>" + itemDescription + "</description>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<quantity>" + qty +"</quantity>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<location></location>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<cube>" + volume +"</cube>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<setup_time>" + setupTime + "</setup_time>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<weight></weight>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<price>"+ itemPrice +"</price>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<countable>"+ inventoryType +"</countable>");
                       myStringXml.Append("<store_code>" + storeStop +"</store_code>");

                  myStringXml.Append("</item>");
                  myStringXml.Append("<items>");



             }



             myStringXml.Append("</service_order>");
             myStringXml.Append("</service_orders>");
```

Comment: Is this in a db table?  what platform?

Comment: Don't use string builder to build XML.

Comment: yes, sql database.  traditional call using sql cmd and con, attempting to build the xml from stringbuilder  .net 4.0

Comment: If you are using SQL server then your best bet is to use `FOR XML`.  If you are using .Net 4.0 then use `LINQ to XML`.   You will find plent of examples on MSDN and SO.

Comment: FYI, calling people a loser isn't a good way to make friends and get help.

Comment: If you have a DataTable then just use dt.WriteXml("filename").  If you need the results in application then use StringWriter and then use dt.WriteXml(writer);

Answer (score 1):

To do this with LINQ you can do something like this.  (I recommend named instead of numbered indexers for the columns but this will do)  I also defined my own schema so I could do it quicker.  You can follow the pattern and get it into any shape you like.

```
var table = new DataTable(); //your table here

var orders = from row in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
             let item = new
             {
                 OrderID = row[0],
                 Account = row[1],
                 ItemID = row[999],
                 Price = row[998],
             }
             group item by new { item.OrderID, item.Account };

var xml = new XElement("orders",
    from order in orders
    select new XElement("order",
        new XAttribute("id", order.Key.OrderID),
        new XAttribute("account", order.Key.Account),
        new XElement("items",
            from item in order
            select new XElement("item",
                new XAttribute("id", item.ItemID),
                new XAttribute("price", item.Price)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, again... XML is not a string. Period. Actually, it is a data buffer that looks similar to strings in 80% cases, and other 20% would hurt you much.

What can be done instead? Two options at least:

- If you have some business-layer classes that represent those DB-originated data instances, you can decorate appropriate fields with XmlElement attribute and all that auto-serialization staff, see MSDN sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx
- Create structured XML model by hand: create a document, append root node, then append nested sub-nodes etc. etc. etc. See that MSDN sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild(v=vs.110).aspx

First option is most convenient due automatic serialization/deserialization, 2nd one is more flexible (as not all XML schemas can be achieved by serialization attributes). And never ever compose your XML as a "string by chunks" because you can get bad-formed XML, incorrect XML content encoding and many other pains. Happy coding!